# Unrecognized element 'add' in web config for giving the role in c#

Tags: c#

i tried using the code in web config but it still gives the error and im unable to run the program and throws configuration error
please give the solution for that above image

above code written in my web.config-

Comment: show your web.config

Comment: <roleManager enabled="true" defaultProvider="MyProvider">
    <providers>
     <clear></clear>
     <add name="MyProvider" type="OFRSWEBAPP.MyRoleProvider.SiteRole"/>
    </providers>
   </roleManager>

Comment: roleManager should be declared under the <system.web>, so please make sure if it's in the correct place on your web.config file

Comment: yes its under system.web only-

Comment: <system.web>
    
   <authentication mode="Forms">
    <forms loginUrl="~/FlightReservationSystem/Login" defaultUrl="~/" timeout="20" slidingExpiration="true"></forms>
        </authentication>
   <roleManager enabled="true" defaultProvider="MyProvider">
    <providers>
     <clear></clear>
     <add name="MyProvider" type="OFRSWEBAPP.MyRoleProvider.SiteRole"/>
    </providers>
   </roleManager>
   <compilation debug="true" targetFramework="4.8" />
   <httpRuntime targetFramework="4.8" />
  </system.web>